# TCP KeepAlive machanism doesn't work on MacOS

Tags: macos, tcp, upload, stack, chromium

I have a http client on mac to upload a file to server,

using the chromium net stack which enable tcp socket keepalive default with timeout 45 seconds,

but when I switch the Wifi to 4G during the normal upload stage, capturing tcp packet using tcpdump,

there is no keepalive packets show up.

I want to know why that happened, and how to make it effective

tcp client code on macos:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netdb.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int args, char** argv){
    int fd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(fd<0) return 0;

    cout << "tcp fd created: " << fd << endl;
    int on = 1;
    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, sizeof(on))) {
        cout << "Failed to set SO_KEEPALIVE on fd: " << fd;
        return 0;
    }

    int delay = 10;
    if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPALIVE, &delay, sizeof(delay))) {
        cout << "Failed to set TCP_KEEPALIVE on fd: " << fd;
        return 0;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in peer_addr_;
    auto server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    bzero((char*)&peer_addr_, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    peer_addr_.sin_family = AF_INET;
    peer_addr_.sin_port = htons(7777);
    bcopy((char*)server->h_addr, (char*)&peer_addr_.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);

    int rv = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&peer_addr_, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if(rv < 0) return 0;
    while(true){
        cout << "client online ..." << endl;
        sleep(3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested without turning off the wifi，and it work correctly， only failed when no wifi or switch to another network

Comment: Where do you measure the TCP keep alive packets? Since these should only be send by the client if the connection is idle you need to check at the client side. If you only check at the server side there might be some middlebox in between which discards these payload-less data.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I measured that at client side using both wireshark and tcpdump, 

when I restore the network, the last keepalive packet will be sent and rst received.

Comment: Let me understand: you put an interface down (WiFi) but still expect to see traffic (TCP keep-alive) on this interface?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Not exactly, network switch is I wanted, like 4G switch to wifi, or wifi A to wifi B

Comment: Still not clear. Is there an active interface with a valid route where these packets could be send through? For example - if one does a ping to the target, does it even show up in the tcpdump if the WiFi is down?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I reedit the description of the question, actually if the Wifi is down, there is no keepalive packets show up. You can test that on your machine,  and observe the flow between client and server(use ncat listen the fixed port like 7777)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225143/discussion-between-berte-colin-and-steffen-ullrich).